# Neural Networks : Padding Numpy array to match largest shape

Tags: numpy, neural-network, mnist

After watching videos and reading some tutorials on `Neural Networks` I [implemented one](http://sdc.autojazari.com/deep-learning) using the [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset and TensorFlow.

Now I have written `(my own)` *very simple* library; 4 classes, and I want to use it on the [GTSD](http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsdb&subsection=dataset) dataset

I realize the complexity of the task but it is for learning purposes and to cement the ideas, not just learn `TensorFlow` syntax

In the [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset there are `784` inputs, one per pixel in image.

The traffic signs in [GTSD](http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsdb&subsection=dataset) have different shapes, so I have a idea that follows this pseudocode

```
1) Read sample image files per classification type
2) Determine largest rows,cols for classification type
3) Zero-fill smaller samples to match largest shape
```

I am having some trouble with the idea of how [numpy.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) does this.

Say theres an image with `114` rows and another with `122` cols and I've determined those are the `max` rows and cols.  If there's another image that's `(36, 42)` how do I **pad** this to the `(114,122)` shape?

Finally is padding the only step that would solve the problem of variable feature length per input?